# Input validation in textbox using specific letters

Tags: .net, vb.net

I'm trying to limit the letters you can use in a 5 text boxes to "D, H, C and S"

The code I have is:

```
suit(0) = txtSuit1.Text
suit(1) = txtSuit2.Text
suit(2) = txtSuit3.Text
suit(3) = txtSuit4.Text
suit(4) = txtSuit5.Text


    For i As Integer = 0 To 4
        If suit(i) <> "D" And suit(i) <> "H" And suit(i) <> "C" And suit(i) <> "S" And suit(i) = "" Then
            MessageBox.Show("Choose a suit using D for Diamonds, H for Hearts, C for Clubs or S for Spades")
        End If
    Next'
```

Even if I put in random letters, the message box will not show up. And using Or instead of And makes the message box pop up every time.

Also having an issue with throwing a message box in this code if the box if left blank:

```
            cards(0) = CInt(txtCard1.Text)
            cards(1) = CInt(txtCard2.Text)
            cards(2) = CInt(txtCard3.Text)
            cards(3) = CInt(txtCard4.Text)
            cards(4) = CInt(txtCard5.Text)



    For i As Integer = 0 To 4
        If cards(i) > 13 Or cards(i) < 1 Or Not IsNumeric(cards(i)) Or cards(i) = "" Then
            MessageBox.Show("Enter a number between 1-13")
        End If
    Next'
```

Every time there is a blank box, I get an error saying string "" to type 'Integer' is not valid.
How do I go about throwing a message box when the textbox is left blank?

Comment: Use a combobox for Suits instead - it will only allow them to pick a valid item, then use the first letter of the selection if you only want {D, H, C, S}.  Also, one question per post, please...for numbers, use a NumericUpDown

Comment: You shouldn't use `And` and `Or` for  boolean tests only for binary disjonction/conjonction. Prefer `AndAlso` and `OrElse` instead (+ side they are short-circuiting). *(Maybe use `Select Case` instead of `If` when you have multiple similar condition to check)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is usually better to prevent users from being able to enter bad data rather than write code to scold them when they do not.  For that, use a `ComboBox` for suits and a `NumericUpDown` for the card ranks.

Otherwise, simple code to validate what you have collected:

```
' suit is your string array of suit letters
Dim suitCodes = {"H", "C", "D", "S"}

Dim bValid As Boolean = True
For Each s As String In suit
    If suitCodes.Contains(s) = False Then
        ' optionally save 's' and report it as bad
        bValid = False
    End If
Next
If bValid = False Then
    MessageBox.Show("Please enter only 'H, C, S, D' for suits")
End If
```

If I had to do it this way, I would normally collect *all* the bad values and report them to the user rather than a generic message.  But, never put a MessageBox inside a loop - they only need to be told once, told once, told once.

---

Much the same thing can initially be done for numerics, but you have to allow that they enter text rather than numerals.  For that use `TryParse` rather than `CINT`:

```
' cards is a bad var name
Dim ranks(4) As Int32

If Integer.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, ranks(0)) Then
    If ranks(0) < 1 OrElse ranks(0) > 13 Then bValid = False
Else
    bValid = False
End If
```

But you have a bigger problem looming.  In most cases, Aces are high but you appear to be storing them as 1 (Lo). You don't want a pair of threes to appear to beat a pair of Aces, so you should convert them:

```
Dim temp As Int32
If Integer.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, temp) Then
    If temp > 0 AndAlso temp < 14 Then
        If temp = 1 Then
            ' store Ace as Hi:
            ranks(0) = 14
        Else
            ranks(0) = temp
        End If
    End If
Else
    bValid = False
End If
```

Alternatively, have them enter values from 2-14.

Comment: You could have used `Array.Exists` instead of the looping construct (or was it meant to be more "beginner oriented" ?)